# How to cross a road by foot in a country that drives on the "other" side of the road

Tags: safety, walking, mongolia, traffic

I'm currently in UB, Mongolia, which has a combination of fairly aggressive driving (though I bet the comments section will list worse countries) and driving on the opposite side of the road than I'm used to in Australia. I've sometimes been looking in the wrong direction for traffic while crossing the road, or assumed that a car coming towards me will safely pass on the far side of the road before I reach it.

How can I handle cars driving on the opposite side of the road to what I'm used to?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20791/3221

Comment: @pnuts when I'm in the UK I generally look both ways repeatedly at around twice the rate of looking back and forth I use in New York City (my home). This seems to work fairly well (and better than a once-in-each-direction look which is often in the wrong order).

Comment: For countries that drive on right side, check your left side first. For countries that drive on left side, check your right side first. In any case, remember to look both ways before stepping on the road.

Comment: I'm curious how it even matters what site the cars are driving. As long cars drive in both directions you will allways miss 50% when jsut looking into 1 direction. Or what am I missing here?

Comment: @Zaibis Question is in which direction you look first (and how to force yourself to really do it). If you don't pay attention, you could already (semi-automatically) step on the road before glancing in the other direction.

Comment: Op you already live in a country with `fairly aggressive driving`. I don't know how you don't have this habit of looking both ways before crossing. I live in India, and most of the time, there is no correct side and no wrong side. You must look both sides to stay alive. In fact kids are taught to look both sides.

Comment: @Zaibis: The idea is that on busier/wider (> 1 lane per direction) roads, you can first concentrate on the direction of the lanes directly ahead, cross those until you reach the "middle" of the road, and then wait there for a gap in the other direction.

Comment: I have suggested a change in title, as I found the current one rather misleading. By "being a pedestrian", I expected information on how to walk alongside/on a road, which involves a whole bunch of other behavioral guidelines, rather than just crossing it. (After all, you may well have to cross a road while essentially being a motorist ... who happened to park vice-versa of their destination.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ah ok got it. but I also didn't get from OP that he actually was asking where to look first, but got the impression he asks about where to look at all.

Comment: check both ways and then the first way again.

Comment: @pnuts: Hm, debatable, I'd say. The question *can* be read in such a way that it exclusively refers to crossing the road. And, after reading the existing answers, it seems like they fully answer the "crossing the road" part without really answering anything else (such as "walking along the road"), which is usually an indication that this question is good as it is, and the other facets should receive their own questions (or, taken differently, if the other facets were to be explicitly included here, this goes into the "asking several things at a time" direction).

Comment: @pnuts: And, for what it's worth: "I disagree with Relaxed's *Question is in which direction you look first*." - it seems [your first thought after reading the question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77635/how-to-cross-a-road-by-foot-in-a-country-that-drives-on-the-other-side-of-the?noredirect=1#comment171933_77635) *was* to explain in which direction to look (first) ;)

Comment: @pnuts I am not sure, I just mentioned one way it could be relevant. But if the question is how to cross a large road with lots of traffic and a central reservation, then the advice given here (switching all the time) isn't necessarily the best way to go. What people who have to cross motorways professionally are instructed to do is to never let their eyes off the incoming traffic (and walk, not run!). You have to take your time before starting and know which side to look, obviously.

Comment: @Zaibus: it's a bad habit and I don't recommend it, but here in the UK (drive on the left), if I'm walking down the street with the road to my left then I know that oncoming traffic is closer to me, and traffic from behind me is further. So to cross, I can see there's nothing coming right at me, then I step into the road and simultaneously look over my shoulder. So if I'm wrong what side of the road they're driving on because I'm acting on habit, then I might step right in front of something. If all goes to plan then I can step back off the road when there's something coming from behind me.

Comment: ... obviously what I *should* do is check the road before stepping into it, regardless of what side of it people should or actually are driving on. But the habit only becomes a liability when I actually am wrong: one-way streets and foreign countries.

Comment: Looking both ways is best, once in Germany I nearly crossed a road and saw a car coming on their "wrong" side of the road - which would be correct for the UK but had got in the habit of checking both ways even more there and certainly didn't expect that so saved me walking into it's path had I only checked what would be correct way there!

Comment: Follow a chicken.

Comment: In Australia you would have been taught to look left then right, then cross. You need to reverse this. Immediately before crossing you should be checking the direction where the immediate danger will be coming from. On any reasonably busy street, it's not going to be clear in both directions at the same time, so timing is absolutely crucial.

Comment: It's safe to assume that in most developing countries, most drivers are complete, utter, inconsiderate a-holes. Always remember this. The only person who values your life is you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44728/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-grimm-how-to-cross-a-road-by-foot-in-a-country).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you travel a lot, it's a good idea to get in the habit of ***always, always*** checking both directions before stepping out, wherever you are, without habitually favouring either direction first:

- If it's a habit, you won't step out in front of a car if you get it wrong and forget you're in an other-side-of-the-road country momentarily (e.g. after a few drinks)
- Many cities, especially narrow winding European streets, have complicated one way systems where a pedestrian might not realise cars come from the other way, or narrow two-lane streets so choked with parked vehicles both sides that everyone drives down the middle. If you habitually check both ways, you won't miss the Audi bombing down the direction you haven't looked yet at 35 mph in a 20 mph area while checking their stocks portfolio on their iPhone
- Many cities in developed countries have growing numbers of cyclists, a small but significant minority of whom go any direction at speed and don't give a
- Many cities in developing countries have growing numbers of '[okada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okada_(motorcycle_taxi))'-style [motorbike taxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle_taxi), a large and significant majority of whom go any direction at speed and don't give a
- There are many other location-specific hazards that can splatter the unwary like this. For example, trams, which are often extremely quiet and can be coming from unexpected directions. [This is how Gaudi died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoni_Gaud%C3%AD#Death). Don't be like Gaudi
- In some countries, there's an unwritten rule that if your car is expensive-looking enough, and/or if you have the right status signifier (e.g. diplomatic or government plates), you can drive on the wrong side of the road if you're in a hurry and it's everyone else's problem if they're in your way. Sometimes, as a courtesy, these drivers put their hazard lights on while driving on the wrong side of the road, to let you know they're not doing it by accident.
- Some locations naively installed speed bumps that only cover half of the road (for example, the half approaching a school entrance but not the half of the road leading away from it), which many drivers like to cheerfully slalom while driving at double the speed limit, weaving in and out of the wrong side of the road around the half-a-speed-bump at speed like an Olympic skier.
- Then there's all the "should never happen but sometimes does" ridiculous stuff that can happen occasionally in any country, like people driving on the wrong side of the road because they're drunk, high, confused, in a road race or police chase, reversing fast like an idiot because they drove past their stop and don't want to turn around...
- ...or maybe the driver is [also a foreigner having trouble with this "other side of the road" malarky](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18314/3145). When people make these mistakes, it tends to be on quiet streets where there are no other cars as a reference - i.e. exactly the sort of place you might step out too quickly...

If you always habitually check both ways, you're fine even if you didn't notice or momentarily forgot you were somewhere that has one or more of these hazards.

[image] [image]

Comment: When I check both directions, I do it multiple times. Left, Right, Left, Right and then some more.

Comment: I have to disagree with the final *If you always habitually check both ways, ... hazards.* As Relaxed wrote in a comment *...in which direction you look first (and how to force yourself to really do it). If you don't pay attention, you could already (semi-automatically) step on the road before glancing in the other direction*. From experience, it is very hard to change your LRL habit to a RLR habit and *not* start stepping onto the road when you have seen that the initial L is clear. The essential safety measure is *not* to look both ways, it is to look both ways *more than you usually do*.

Comment: @JanDoggen well I certainly didn't say or mean "only check them once"... whole point is to habitually not favour a default direction, ever, even at home (even on a one way street!), and always check both *at least* once before having stepped out.

Comment: "Many cities in developed countries have growing numbers of cyclists, a small but significant minority of whom go any direction at speed and don't give a" In many cities this is even legally sanctioned.

Comment: What don't they give? The suspense is killing me :).

Comment: @J.Constantine You can: that's what bounties are for. Not saying you should, but you certainly can.

Comment: "My mom reminds me to _look both ways_ before we step onto the sidewalk." Er, seriously? Because she's worried about joggers or something? _My_ mom reminds me to look both ways before we step **off* the sidewalk.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: pedestrians on bikes. Frankly the only problem I have with this answer is how blasé it is about being on the pavement/sidewalk. That's fair enough considering the question is only about roads. But the notion that someone willing to drive up the wrong side of the road won't also come up onto the pavement/sidewalk when it suits them, is a dangerous complacancy. Just assume motorists are trying to kill you, and you won't be unpleasantly surprised.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, what they don't give is a toot

Comment: @SteveJessop A pedestrian is somebody who is on foot. Cyclists are not pedestrians. Actually, cyclists on the sidewalk is a good point but I'm pretty sure the cartoon didn't mean to say that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: "pedestrians on bikes" is a disparaging idiom for cyclists who don't use the road when they should. I believe the implication is that they're abusively and incorrectly trying assume the rights of pedestrians as and when it suits them. Agreed though, the people pictured are preparing to step *off* the sidewalk, not onto it. I was just reminded of [this incident](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-manchester-33738163).

Comment: @DavidRicherby The comic explicitly says it was to "make sure no cars are coming," so I read it as intending to be humorous (implying that cars might be driving down the sidewalk.) It's possible that it was just a mistake, though.

Comment: Looking both directions is not good enough. You need to look in the appropriate direction, at the appropriate time, unless you're on a quiet country road with little traffic.

Comment: I'm form right-side-driving country and I look left-right-left before I step into  the road. Crossing road in UK was awkward - I didn'n expect the car form right side to miss me that close...

Comment: Even in places where traffic is civilized, you *still* get the occasional wrong-way driver...yikes!  (I distinctly recall a time when I was young when I had to save my grandfather from becoming one as he was cutting a left turn too tightly...)

Answer (score 18):

I (and the whole country) was raised to do look left, right and again to the left before stepping off the curb. Obviously less efficient to do it in an opposite direction country but if you get used to a three step look around you will be fine in most places.

Comment: If you're in a LHD country, always look left first because you will get hit from the left first. The amount of time I see people look right first when they want to turn left and creep into my lane before they look left is infuriating. Other way around in RHD coutries, obviously.

Comment: @akadian: I don't quite understand. The question refers to pedestrians crossing a road, not to drivers making turns. And pedestrians in an LHD country will first get hit from the right.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I do realize that, but a pedestrian will get hit from the left side first either way. I guess I just felt the need to rant about drivers who feel the need to inch up. I apologize for that.

Comment: @akadian: I suppose I just don't understand what you mean. In LHD traffic, the lane the pedestrian steps onto first has traffic coming from the *right*, so they will first be hit from the right.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Eh, got it confused with LHD cars and traffic. My mistake.

Answer (score 15):

**Always expect traffic from both sides.**
Always assume the lane you are going to cross is a one way street/lane and you do not know which way the traffic is supposed to go.
If there is a safe point in the crossing, stop and look around again, again both directions and not expecting traffic to come from a certain side.

**Do not hurry.**
First spend more time looking left, right, left, (or the other way around if in a country with traffic on the left) than you would at home. Better miss an oportunity to cross than start walking when you are not yet sure.
Allow yourself more time to cross the road than you expect to need, that allows for cars on the far side where you expect them to be on the near side, and for cars that slow down before they reach you.

**Back home does not mean safe.**
And very importantly, when you return home, keep in the habbit for a couple of weeks, (or forever,) as it can be rather dangerous if you have adjusted to traffic on the wrong side of the road and you forget, when falling in routine, that you are back home.
I nearly got hit by a car I had not seen, not looked for, on a road crossing I had been using all my life, very close to my grandmothers house. I had so gotten used to looking the wrong way.
In the years since I have learned to always look both ways, even when I know the road I am about to cross on my daily commute is a one way road.
The famous last words of a victim: **Cars do not come from that way!**

Answer (score 0):

Don't jaywalk, always cross at corners.  Look both ways, twice.  Never step off the curb to check traffic.

A few years ago a Japanese scholar visiting chicago stepped off a curb looking right to check traffic.  Unfortunately there was traffic, on the left.  He was run over and killed.  Tragic, but true.

Comment: Not the only such tale I know of.

Comment: "Don't jaywalk." There is no such thing as "jaywalking" in many places, so that's not meaningful advice. In many places, there are few marked crossings, precisely because it's legal for a pedestrian to cross the road anywhere.

Comment: And "always cross at corners" is terrible advice. Corners limit visibility and, in any case, there might not be one nearby.

Comment: "Don't jaywalk" is very sensible advice, meaning "in jurisdictions where there exists a crime of jaywalking, do not commit it". "Always cross at corners" is terrible advice where it is legal to cross elsewhere. At a junction, the pedestrian needs to check for traffic coming from more than two directions, whereas between corners you only have two directions of traffic to worry about (plus any parked vehicles). Take the easier, safer route when it's available.

Comment: @SteveJessop So when one says "don't smoke pot" it means "in jurisdictions where there exists a crime of smoking pot, do not commit it"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I don't think so, no. I mean, it might be that the person saying "don't smoke pot" is only giving that advice on the presumption it's illegal, but nothing in those three words means that. But "smoking pot" describes the act regardless of whether it's legal or not, whereas "jaywalking" specifically means crossing the road illegally. If someone were to say "don't cross the road", then they'd mean even if it's legal.

Comment: One example that does come up, though, is that when people say "don't take drugs", they usually don't mean "refuse medication prescribed by your doctor". So sometimes you need to look for context to figure out the intended scope of some advice. But I don't think "jaywalking" is ever used to mean "crossing the road where it is legal to do so", so there's no such confusion here. I may be wrong, in which case I've misunderstood the advice here.

Comment: my advice against jaywalking is not motivated by legal or ethical concerns.  it motivated by the practical observation that motorists are more likely to be alert for pedestrian

Comment: sorry, hit the wrong button.  motorists expect traffic at intersections and so cam be expected to be more alert to pedestrians at corners.

Comment: I was knocked down by a car when crossing at an intersection in Canada. Car was at fault. However it re-iterated for me a very important lesson. Cross when safe, not just when legal. The local I was with, who was kind of pulling me along was concerned about making the crossing while signal was still white. I should instead have trusted my instincts and waited for the next signal. It's extremely important to make sure you make eye contact with motorists waiting at the intersection.